# Changing background color in jQuery map highlighter

Tags: jquery, dictionary, highlight, area

I have a store locator with this plugin. I want if each area has a store this area's background have a different color from the others. So it's about  styling subject it can be. I don't know how. Perhaps this map needs trigger to highlight.

plugin home page = http://davidlynch.org/js/maphilight/docs/

Comment: what is your question? Try using real sentences not google translate.

Comment: Google translate? The question is "How can I change the area's background?" Question is quite clear => "I want if each area has a store this area's background have a different color from the others."

Answer (score 1):

I resolve my solve myself. I used jQuery Metadata plugin.

http://plugins.jquery.com/node/8774 I get it later I used highlighter's option in area tag as class. Like that;

```
class="{alwaysOn:true, fillOpacity: 0.3, fillColor: '0ff000'}"
```

By the way sometimes poor english can be strong language ;) Thanks.

Comment: your link gives me 'Page not found'